# The Apache2 configtest failed

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd

Can anyone help me with this error.

> [Failed] starting web server: apache2 failed!

Output of config test was:

> Chown: changing ownership of '/var/lock/apache2.Nxr1S1Hr6b': Operation not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another `apache2` running?

```
ps aux | grep apache2
```

If so, kill it (`pkill -9 apache2`). If the file still persists, what are the permissions on that file?

```
ls -l /var/lock/apache2.Nxr1S1Hr6b
```

Probably you can remove the file, which should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the user ID that owns `/var/lock/apache2.Nxr1S1Hr6b`:

```
ls -l /var/lock/apache2.Nxr1S1Hr6b
```

or maybe
    ls -ld /var/lock/apache2.Nxr1S1Hr6b

If the ownership of that file or directory is not the same as the user ID in the `httpd.conf` file's "User" directive, I'd change the owner to that user ID.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested all the solutions you guys provided but none work .. what I noticed is that when ever I attempted to start apache2 and the error comes up, it creates a new dir with diff extension  /var/lock/apache2.uEM,
/var/lock/apache2.gpk etc